# React Conditional Render and Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am controlling what component should be shown on my applications screen via the state and a switch statement in the main render function. I am writing this in react-native but this is a react structure question.

I also have a Navbar component that I would ideally like to only rerender when the user clicks on a link in the Navbar itself, but I don't know of a great way to do this with how I have the switch statement setup now, it seems like I will have to rerender the Navbar every time depending on what condition is met by the state.

My question is, is there a way that I can still use conditional rendering of components in the render method like I am below AND have a component that is always rendered at the top of the screen like the Navbar? I know this is possible with things like React Router, but is there a better way to structure it without using a tool like React Router or having to rerender the NavBar component every time?

```html
import React from 'react';

import GPS from './GPS/gps';
import Home from './Home';
import Photo from './Camera/Photo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      hasCameraPermission: null,
      type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
      currentView: null,
      currentImage: null,
      navigation: 'Overview'
    };

    this.updateNavigation = this.updateNavigation.bind(this);
  }

  updateNavigation(view) { //Update view function
    this.setState({currentView: view});
  }


  render() {
    const { currentView } = this.state;

    switch(currentView) {
      case null:
      return (
        <Home updateNav={this.updateNavigation} />
        );
        break;

      case 'GPS':
      return (
        <View>
          <GPS />
          <Text onPress={() => this.setState({currentView: null})}>Back</Text>
        </View>
      );
        break;

      case 'Camera':
      return (
          <Photo updateNav={this.updateNavigation} />
       );
       break;

       case 'viewPicture':
       return (
        <View>
          <Image source={{uri: this.state.currentImage.uri}} style={{width: this.state.currentImage.width/10, height: this.state.currentImage.height/12}} />
        </View>
       );
       break;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Always keep render as much as clean.

You can use && operator to do the same instead of using switch case. Use && operator and check every case and render accordingly. Check below code for better understanding.

```
render() {
    const { currentView } = this.state;
    return(
      {currentView == null && (
        <Home updateNav={this.updateNavigation} />
        )}
      {currentView == "GPS" && (
        <View>
          <GPS />
          <Text onPress={() => this.setState({currentView: null})}>Back</Text>
        </View>
        )}

      {currentView == "Camera" && (
        <View>
          <Photo updateNav={this.updateNavigation} />
        </View>
        )}

      {currentView == "viewPicture" && (
        <View>
          <Image source={{uri: this.state.currentImage.uri}} style={{width: this.state.currentImage.width/10, height: this.state.currentImage.height/12}} />
        </View>
        )}
    )

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would there be a way to render something like a Navbar component always at the beginning of the render method, but without having to explicitly put it in a condition using the && operator for each component?

Comment: Yeah you can return Nav bar component without any condition so that will render always. My bad for current View value null I added GPS component instead of Home. I edited that now.