# How to render only specific components in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to render only some components in Reactjs

```
class UserproPage extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
        <>                 
             <Topbar/>
             <Navbar/>
             <div>
              <h1>Hello</h1>
             </div>
        </>
        )
    }
```

The `<Navbar/>` has menu button that are common to all the pages hence I do not want it to render them every time I click on links on the menu.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Conditional Render and Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410913/react-conditional-render-and-navbar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React conditional render pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348165/react-conditional-render-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

you can make a condition in your `<Navbar/>` component whether you display or not the `menu button`
example :

```
class Navbar extends Component {

let display = true;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>This is my component.</div>
      {display && <button>menu</button>}
    );
  }
}
```

the `menu button` is displayed only when `display variable` is `true`