# How can I make a button change what components are showing in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

So I'm a bit of a beginner to react native, and I'm making an app. I'm using react navigation to get a bottom navigation bar, but I want to make it so that within one of my pages, the user can press a button to change a component. Check out this quick mock-up I made:[image: mockup, part 1]

[image: mockup, part 2]

Basically, I want to make it so that when the user hits button 1, component 1 appears, but when the user hits button 2, component 2 appears instead. How do I show/hide components? Also how would I implement the buttons?

I know this question sounds rather basic but I really couldn't find any kind of tutorial on it. If you have the answer or can at least point me in the direction of a video or blog post that would answer my question, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Conditional Render and Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410913/react-conditional-render-and-navbar) Basically, create a state that stores the active button. And render your components conditionally [React Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check the snippet here. Maintain state for `selected nav time (button click)`, Then do conditional render based selected content type.

```js
const actions = [
  { name: "button 1", type: "b1" },
  { name: "button 2", type: "b2" },
];

const Component = () => {
  const [contentType, setContentType] = React.useState("b1");

  const Content1 = () => <div> Content1 here </div>;
  const Content2 = () => <div> Content2 here </div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {actions.map((action) => (
          <button
            key={action.type}
            style={{
              backgroundColor:
                action.type === contentType ? "lightblue" : "white",
            }}
            onClick={() => setContentType(action.type)}
          >
            {action.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        {contentType === "b1" && <Content1 />}
        {contentType === "b2" && <Content2 />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to try this out to make sure it's exactly what I'm looking for, but thank you so much!